# pytest-testmon fails with TypeError during writting to results

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

*Why `pytest --testmon` fails with the following exception?*

```
=========================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
testmon=True, changed files: 0, skipping collection of 102 files, run variant: default
rootdir: ../my_project
plugins: testmon-0.9.19
collected 0 items / 91 deselected                                                                                                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../my_project/venv3_test/bin/pytest", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "../my_project/venv3_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 93, in main
.....................
  File "../my_project/venv3_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testmon/pytest_testmon.py", line 242, in pytest_sessionfinish
    self.testmon_data.write_data()
  File "../my_project/venv3_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testmon/testmon_core.py", line 197, in write_data
    self._write_attribute('mtimes', self.source_tree.mtimes)
  File "../my_project/venv3_test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testmon/testmon_core.py", line 160, in _write_attribute
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'o'
```

With the following libraries installed through `pip`:

```
pytest==5.3.5
pytest-watch==4.2.0
pytest-testmon==0.9.19
```

I'm using python3.7, tried to change pytest-testmon version tp 1.0.2, but it also fails

Comment: Line 160 in `testmon_core` of version 1.0.2 [is empty](https://github.com/tarpas/pytest-testmon/blob/63adfc7ed4e0dac77e2d24d5937a72d0df3dc1d0/testmon/testmon_core.py#L160), are you sure the trace is correct?

Comment: @hoefling sorry, was testing on different versions. The current stack is from v0.9.19. But 1.0.2 has the same error

Comment: Ah, I see - can you reproduce in your repo only or with an arbitrary test (is it an issue with the tests in your project or the `testmon` package)? First thing to try is to get rid of the cache: delete the `.pytest_cache` dir and the `.testmondata` db and try again.

Comment: @hoefling even after removing `.pytest_cache/` & `.testmondata`, and running `pytest --testmon` from folder with single one-line test it fails with the same error. Looks like the issue with `testmon` package

Comment: @hoefling I found the issue, `testmon` was borken by https://pypi.org/project/JSON-Datetime/ v0.0.5

Comment: Nice, would you kindly add a short answer?

Comment: @hoefling sure, will add in few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `json-datetime==0.0.5` dependency breaking `testmon`. It's enought importing:

```
import jsondatetime  # comment this line and the exception will disappear:

def test_something():
  assert 1 == 1
```